# How to merge / join with pandas Index type

Tags: pandas

### Problem Statement

(note: the "sample data" section below is more succinct)

I have a pandas index:

```
Index(['RNF14', 'UBE2Q1', 'UBE2Q2', 'RNF10', 'RNF11', 'RNF13', 'REM1', 'REM2',
       'C16orf13', 'MVB12B',
       ...
       'MFAP1', 'CWC22', 'PLRG1', 'PRPF40A', 'SAP30BP', 'PIK3R1', 'MYPN',
       'RBMX2', 'USP12', 'CHERP'],
      dtype='object', length=854)
```

It represents a list of keys, and the indices of those keys in the `Index` are what matter to me. (e.g. `nodes.get_loc('PLRG1')  # => 846`)

Now I also have a list of observations, each of which has an associated key (result of `df.info()` below):

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 58 entries, 0 to 57
Data columns (total 2 columns):
name     58 non-null object
prize    58 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1), object(1)
```

The `name` column is a column of names like those in my Index. I want to do a join, basically identical to a Dataframe merge, with my Dataframe and Index, such that each row in my Dataframe gets the appropriate numerical ID from my Index.

I can't use Dataframe.merge:

```
ValueError: can not merge DataFrame with instance of type <class 'pandas.indexes.base.Index'>
```

What should I do?

A larger question: what is the pandas `Index` type for? I feel like I might be misusing it, despite the fact that, from an abstract standpoint, what I need here is clearly an "Index".

### Some sample data:

```
index = pd.Index(['RNF14', 'UBE2Q1', 'UBE2Q2', 'RNF10'])

# dataframe looks like: 
    name    prize
0   RNF10   0.81
1   UBE2Q2  0.29
2   RNF14   2.68

# result I'm looking for: 
    name    prize
3   RNF10   0.81
2   UBE2Q2  0.29
0   RNF14   2.68
```

Comment: @Mitch, I'm still kind of confused about pandas indices, as you can see. I might be using them entirely incorrectly in the first place?

Comment: Could you explain where new index values (in your desired data set) come from? Do you have another series, etc.?

Comment: With `df` being your DataFrame and `index` being your Index, you can do `df.set_index(index.get_indexer(df['name']))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the DataFrame's [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html#pandas-dataframe-set-index) method combined with the Index's [`get_indexer`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_indexer.html#pandas-index-get-indexer) method:

```
import pandas as pd

index  = pd.Index(['RNF14', 'UBE2Q1', 'UBE2Q2', 'RNF10']) 
df     = pd.DataFrame([['RNF10', 0.81],['UBE2Q2',0.29],['RNF14',2.68]], columns=['name','prize'])
new_df = df.set_index(index.get_indexer(df['name']))
```

This will give

```
In [5]: df
Out[5]: 
     name  prize
0   RNF10   0.81
1  UBE2Q2   0.29
2   RNF14   2.68

In [6]: new_df
Out[6]:
     name  prize
3   RNF10   0.81
2  UBE2Q2   0.29
0   RNF14   2.68
```

Comment: Hi @hooy, thanks for answering my question! My broader question though was: am I even using the right datastructure in pandas?

Comment: And secondly, will this be graceful if some of the names in `df` are not in `index` and vice versa?

Comment: It looks like it does indeed "fail" gracefully

Comment: Hard to say whether you are using the right data structure, seeing as how you haven't explained _why_ you need the functionality you asked for (also, I'm not sure whether you are talking about the `DataFrame` or the `Index` here). I'd recommend reading Wes McKinney's book _Python for Data Analysis_ (2012), which is set for a 2nd edition release in 2017, for a good intro to `pandas` (Wes created `pandas`). There it is stated: "pandas’s Index objects are responsible for holding the axis labels and other metadata
(like the axis name or names)." The online documentation for pandas is also (1/2)

Comment: a good source to information, where it is said about `Index` objects: "Index also provides the infrastructure necessary for lookups, data alignment, and reindexing." And if some name in `df` are not present in `index` the proposed method will yield an index value of `-1` for these entries. If some names in `index` are not present in `df`, well, it has no effect on the result.